Would you use blockchain or not in this case?
Disclaimer: I'm not sure if this question belongs here, please suggest another place if you have one.
I'm trying to figure out what would be my best strategy:
I need to develop an internal coin/tokens/currency system, however you want to call it :-). The closest analogy I can come up with is when you visit a festival, you have to convert your money into their token, then during the festival you buy stuff with their tokens using your phone instead of directly using money. It's kind of the same, you sell goods, you get tokens, with those tokens you can buy other stuff or eventually you can transfer tokens back to money.
In my case:

Pretty small scale (maybe max couple of 1000 users)
It will be in use in a developing country, where internet/electricity access is unstable
I need to support phone to phone transfer of tokens (using NFC)

First thing that came to my mind is using some private hosted blockchain implementation, but I have 0 experience in this area, and I'm also afraid it might be overkill for my use-case. Furthermore, I'm worried about blockchain in combination with flakey internet. Also, a transfer should have 0 fees on it.
So my other option would be that I develop some kind of wallet system, where I try to tackle all difficulties involved myself (security, concurrency, audit-trail, backups, failed transactions because of internet issues...). Or maybe there's some (open-source) library/technology I can use for this?
Backend stack: Python/FastAPI/PostgresQL (hosted in AWS)
Frontend stack: Flutter

http://shouldiuseablockchain.com/

Ha! Care to elaborate?

Why not use a trusted server with an audit log? Since every verifying server would be under your control, you break the fundamental security principle of a blockchain: No single actor should control the verification. What are you trying to protect against that wouldn't be handled by a trusted server?

@user1937198: an inconsistent, slow and possibly untrustworthy network. I think the crux of this question revolves around that, and a central server requires a good and trustworthy network.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@GregBurghardt is correct about the main problem being "flakey internet" however I don't see how blockchain helps with that, since its effectively a CAP problem - if the network is partitioned, you can't make any guarantees about offline transactions.

It is not generally possible to enable digital peer-to-peer transactions (without contacting a central server/blockchain) while preventing double-spend problems. You can create a system like credit cards where money can be spent immediately, and transactions are reconciled at a later time when network is available again, but this enables fraud. Cryptographic techniques (including but not limited to blockchains) can help creating an audit trail that makes fraud easier to detect retroactively. In practice, the best approach is to leverage the smartphone's DRM/TMP/app-integrity features.

Whilst Internet maybe unstable, can you achive a reliable local network? Then run a trusted server on site? So long as there's only one place you can spend tokens, you can avoid double spend, even if the tokens are generated off site.

A fundamental problem with block chain in this regard that I see is that it doesn't really allow you to adjust values. People are going to come to you with complaints about over/under charges, fraudulent charges, and refunds, and if you use blockchain, there won't be anything you can do about them.

Reasons not to use a blockchain:

Can't cancel or unwind transactions, so you can't handle errors or frauds by your users.
No privacy for transactions. This may not matter, or it may matter a lot.
Proof-of-work blockchains are very energy-inefficient and you don't have enough users for proof-of-stake to be meaningful.
Blockchain doesn't help you much, if at all, with bad connectivity.
Hosted blockchains have usage fees. That's how they make money. Somebody has to pay for the servers, bandwidth and power.
Reputational issues: there is enough fraud and incompetence in the blockchain and cryptocurrency industry that some people will simply refuse to use a blockchain implementation. Trying to persuade them to do so will reinforce their suspicion that this is a scam. Speaking personally, you would have to commit imprisonable offences to get me to use a blockchain-based system for anything, and I would be acting under clear and obvious legal duress.


You can't really cancel a classical transaction as well. You can refund, but you can refund crypto as well. And so in both cases it is based on trust. The history of escrows is far older than that of cryptocurrency. But I suppose there is a slight difference that once transaction is finalized you cannot get the money back forcefully. Whether this is good or bad depends on point of view.
